# Encrypt output of apt-listchanges prior to sending email

Tags: apt, gpg

Consider the following scenario:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

I am prompted by `apt-get` whether to accept and install the pending updates. First, since I have `apt-listchanges` installed, it will interrupt and display whether I want to have the changelogs of the upgraded packages. There is also an option to send the changelogs by email.

I want to have the changelogs sent by email. I want the emails to send just that, not the rest of the `apt-get` output.

My difficulty is that I want to encrypt these emails. (Why? Because if there's an unpatched vulnerability on my servers, I don't want that information to become public.)

If I was running a command to get the output, I would just pipe it into gpg:

```
… | gpg --encrypt …
```

But `apt-listchanges` is executed indirectly by `apt-get upgrade`. It knows the list of packages that it's upgraded, I don't.

How can I make `apt-get upgrade` run `apt-listchanges`, making it send the output by email, but encrypting the email?

Comment: Is will be more valuable instead of asking for a recipe/script, understanding how PGP and public/private encryption works.

Comment: I'm well aware of how PGP and asymmetric encryption works. This is a technical question on how to pipe the output through `pgp` prior to sending. Definitely not on how to encrypt text!

Comment: https://www.zulius.com/how-to/send-encrypted-email-from-shell-scripts-cron/

Comment: It's soleley about apt-listchanges! Forget everything regarding cron! My cron output is already encrypted!

Comment: You seem to already have a script, `encrypt.sh`, that does what you want. So, it looks like you could simply pipe any program's output into that script, and then the encrypted output to your e-mail-sending program. If not, perhaps you can explain in more detail how what you are asking for is different?

Comment: Consider the following scenario: run apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. You are then prompted by apt-get wether to accept and install the pending updates. After confirming apt-listchanges will interrupt and prompt wether I want to have The Changelogs of the upgraded packages sent via mail. So, however, I do want to have those changelogs sent, but solely them - without the rest of apt-get output. Following that, piping the whole output into my encrypt.sh script is not what I intend to do.
I think this issue is very plausible if you know apt-listchanges itself.

Comment: @Matthias Your original question was incomprehensible. Knowing how apt-listchanges is typically used, I think I've guessed your difficulty, so I edited your question accordingly. Please review my edit to check that this is indeed what you meant to ask. In the future, when asking a question, please take a minute to re-read it and check that it makes sense to someone who cannot read your mind. Include relevant context (such as, here, why you can't do `apt-listchanges | gpg --encrypt`). Don't include irrelevant digressions (I don't see any way for cron to be relevant here).

Comment: @Gilles I appreciate your efforts for editing this question, you've figured it out.